# Ignite stateful cluster setup issue with k8 on AWS

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, amazon-eks

I am trying to create ignite cluster on aws but I ran into some trouble. My pods are not coming up.
I have followed ignite official documentation for stateful kubernetes deployments on AWS EKS but while creating the ignite cluster I see that pod creation is in hang state.

I have created two separate files one for persistence storage one for wal storage. [Separate Disk for WAL]

I see that the storages are created:

```
    ➜  ignite-configs kubectl get sc
    NAME                               PROVISIONER             AGE

    ignite-persistence-storage-class   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   3h
    ignite-wal-storage-class           kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   3h

    ➜  ignite-configs kubectl describe pod ignite-0
    Name:               ignite-0
    Namespace:          angus-ignite-dev
    Priority:           0
    PriorityClassName:  <none>
    Node:               <none>
    Labels:             app=ignite
                        controller-revision-hash=ignite-76f754f985
                        statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=ignite-0
    Annotations:        <none>
    Status:             Pending
    IP:
    Controlled By:      StatefulSet/ignite
    Containers:
      ignite:
        Image:       apacheignite/ignite:2.6.0
        Ports:       11211/TCP, 47100/TCP, 47500/TCP, 49112/TCP, 10800/TCP, 8080/TCP, 10900/TCP
        Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
        Environment:
          OPTION_LIBS:   ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http
          CONFIG_URI:    https://s3.amazonaws.com/009my-bucket009/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml
          IGNITE_QUIET:  false
          JVM_OPTS:      -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
        Mounts:
          /persistence from ignite-persistence (rw)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from ignite-token-h6m7b (ro)
          /wal from ignite-wal (rw)
    Conditions:
      Type           Status
      PodScheduled   False
    Volumes:
      ignite-persistence:
        Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
        ClaimName:  ignite-persistence-ignite-0
        ReadOnly:   false
      ignite-wal:
        Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
        ClaimName:  ignite-wal-ignite-0
        ReadOnly:   false
      ignite-token-h6m7b:
        Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName:  ignite-token-h6m7b
        Optional:    false
    QoS Class:       BestEffort
    Node-Selectors:  <none>
    Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                     node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
    Events:



      Type     Reason            Age                       From               Message
      ----     ------            ----                      ----               -------
      Warning  FailedScheduling  2m23s (x12033 over 107m)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 15 times)
```

=====================

```
Here are my ignite config files:

ignite-persistence-storage-class.yaml
=====================================

#Amazon AWS Configuration
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ignite-persistence-storage-class  #StorageClass name
  namespace: angus-ignite-dev         #Ignite namespace
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2 #Volume type io1, gp2, sc1, st1. Default: gp2
  zones: us-west-2
```

===========================================================
Here are my storage yaml files for logs and persistence:

## ignite-wal-storage-class.yaml

```
#Amazon AWS Configuration
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ignite-wal-storage-class  #StorageClass name
  namespace: angus-ignite-dev #Ignite namespace
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2 #Volume type io1, gp2, sc1, st1. Default: gp2
  zones: us-west-2
```

======================================================================
Here is my ignite statefulset creation yaml file:

## I have some doubts regarding PV and PVCs. Do I have to declare them somewhere?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: angus-ignite-dev
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  serviceName: ignite
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ignite
      containers:
      - name: ignite
        image: apacheignite/ignite:2.6.0
        env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: https://s3.amazonaws.com/009my-bucket009/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml
        - name: IGNITE_QUIET
          value: "false"
        - name: JVM_OPTS
          value: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 11211 # JDBC port number.
        - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port number.
        - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port number.
        - containerPort: 49112 # JMX port number.
        - containerPort: 10800 # SQL port number.
        - containerPort: 8080 # REST port number.
        - containerPort: 10900 #Thin clients port number.
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/wal"
          name: ignite-wal
        - mountPath: "/persistence"
          name: ignite-persistence
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: ignite-persistence
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "ignite-persistence-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "100Gi"
  - metadata:
      name: ignite-wal
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "ignite-wal-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "100Gi"
```

Comment: figured it out though..on Ignite documentation page one step is missing. that is volume creation step.

Answer (score 0):

With Kubernetes version 1.19 and above using VolumeClaimTemplate with StateFulSets will create PersistentVolumeClaim and PersistentVolume(Provided dynamic provisioning is already set by admin).

So no need of creating separate PV and PVCs if you are using VolumeClaimTemplate.